# Does this SQL Table design make sense for a Currency with a finite amount?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

This is my first post here in StackOverFlow. I need some opinions whether my table design makes sense for a system where users can own a currency and that currency has a finite amount -- like crypto or discount coins in e-commerce.

Here's an example. There's a currency say "Coin" (CurrencyName) with a maximum amount of "1,000" (TotalSupply). Each user in the system can own one so I created an Inventory Table referencing the user id and currency id with an addition of Amounts Owned column. Does it make sense?

**User Table**

- UserId INT PK
- Email VARCHAR(255)
- Password VARCHAR(255)
- RegisterDate DATETIME

**Currency Table**

- CurrencyId INT PK
- CurrecyName VARCHAR(255)
- TotalSupply INT

**Inventory Table**

- CurrencyId INT FK
- UserId INT FK
- AmountOwned INT

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: I see no problem as it is. You may also ask database-design question at  https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If there are no decimals ("*cents*" or "*pennies*") in your currencies, this looks to be a good table setup. There is no control that total owned by all users wouldn't exceed `TotalSupply`.

A good hint would be to use names like `total_owned` instead of `TotalOwned`.

If you decide that you want to use smaller units ("*cents*"), use `DECIMAL` type, `FLOAT` would bring rounding problems.

Comment: How do you put control that the total owned will not exceed total supply? You mean you recommend underscore versus Pascal case? Decimal is a good idea.

Comment: In PostgreSQL you could write the check as a function and use it in a constraint, but I think you can't do it that way in MySQL. Anyway, if you want to do that it's well worth some googling first and only after trying something yourself a new question here :)

Comment: @VesaKarjalainen - Newer versions have some `CHECK` functionality.  However, doesn't he need to check `SUM(AmountOwned)` against `1.0`?

Comment: @RickJames Each currency has max amount of owned between all users set in `total_supply` in `currency` table. That needs to be compared against sum of `amount_owned` in `inventory`. I don't think that's possible, since [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) say you can't use stored functions in `CHECK` constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming cryptocurrency is carried to 18 decimal places, these seem to be the only 'good' datatype choices in MySQL:

```
BIGINT UNSIGNED  -- scaled so that 1e18 in that is your 1.0
DECIMAL(19,18)   -- handles any amount up to (and slightly beyond 1.0)
```

It is probably not worth having a Trigger or Check to validate whether the value exceeds the max, nor whether it is negative.

The first option takes 8 bytes, plus scaling code.  The second takes 9 bytes and handles things like "0.00000123" directly (without scaling).  Both have no roundoff errors (assuming you stick within the 18 digits.)